# OpenCv, Android: cannot edit pixels of camera frame converted to HLS colorspace

Tags: c++, opencv, android

I have a function which receives camera frames and makes contrast/brightness adjustments to them. When I have...

```
void applyContrastBrightnessToFrame(Mat &frame, float contrast, int brightness)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < frame.rows; i++) {
        uchar *basePixel = frame.ptr(i);
        for (int j = 0; j != frame.cols * frame.channels(); j += frame.channels()) {
            int channelsToBlend = min(3, frame.channels()); //never adjust alpha channel
            for (int c = 0; c < channelsToBlend; c++) {
                basePixel[j + c] = saturate_cast<uchar>(basePixel[j + c] * contrast + brightness);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works perfectly.

But when I convert the image to HLS so that I can do these adjustments without ruining the the saturation, pixel manipulations fail...

```
void applyContrastBrightnessToFrame(Mat &frame, float contrast, int brightness)
{
    cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_RGBA2RGB);
    cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_RGB2HLS);
    assert(frame.channels() == 3);


    for (int i = 0; i < frame.rows; i++) {
        uchar *basePixel = frame.ptr(i);
        for (int j = 0; j != frame.cols * frame.channels(); j += frame.channels()) {
            int lumaChannel = 1;
            //all pixel manipulations fail....
            basePixel[j + lumaChannel] = 0;  //setting to a constant
            saturate_cast<uchar>(basePixel[j + lumaChannel] + brightness); //adjusting
        }
    }

    cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_HLS2RGB);
    cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2RGBA);
    assert(frame.channels() == 4);
}
```

Here's what I know: The conversions are successful. When I capture an image from the camera and run it through the same function, the pixel manipulations succeed - this is especially weird since the processing of frames and captured images is identical.

What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you are trying to alter brightness/contrast of a frame, pixel-wise.

So instead of iterating through every pixel from all channels of the frame, you can first split the HLS channels, perform operations and merge them back.

```
void applyContrastBrightnessToFrame(Mat &frame, float contrast, int 
brightness)
{
    cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_RGBA2RGB);
    cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_RGB2HLS);
    vector<Mat> hlsChannels(3);
    split(frame, hlsChannels);
    hlsChannels[1] += brightness; //adding brightness to channel 2(lightness channel)
    merge(hlschannels, frame);
    cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_HLS2RGB);
    cvtColor(frame, frame, CV_BGR2RGBA);
}
```

You can also try looping over the pixels in the lightness channel alone.

Hope this helps!